# Div moves with scrollbar even though position is set to absolute

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to code this website and I'm having a problem with the main content box. Everything else on the page stays stationary and resizes as needed if the window size or resolution changes, however this content box doesn't and if I scroll across it moves with the scrolling.

This is what it should look like permanently (albeit different sizes for different resolutions):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PmyE8p5.png]

This is what happens if the resolution changes from 1920x1080 or the window size changes:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8AHGXxd.png]

Everything is wrapped within a container with this code:

```
#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width:1000px;
}
```

This is the code for the container itself:

```
#content-box {
    width: 90%;
    height: 95%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 143px;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    overflow: hidden;
```

(Yes I'm rubbish at CSS/HTML, so I'd appreciate any tips and solutions people may have).

Thanks!

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: If you do not want it to move you should use position: fixed;

Comment: Images are broken (not got time at the moment to upload them), but: http://jsfiddle.net/bhKfn/

Comment: @Santz I think that should be a solution.

Comment: I tried changing it to fixed but it's still causing an issue. I'll try and link a video tomorrow.

Comment: did my answer solve what you need?

Answer (score 0):

try giving position `fixed` instead of `absolute`..